# How to upgrade rkhunter to most current version?

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, rkhunter

I installed `rkhunter` 1.4.2 but I wanted `rkhunter` 1.4.4.

Currently I receive a warning for:

```
/usr/bin/lwp-request
```

I assume this  warning is in error or the file is corrupt.

Additional error include:

```
Checking /dev for suspicious file types                  [ Warning ]
Checking for hidden files and directories                [ Warning ]
```

To clarify, I added Mozilla Firefox apt to show national flags in the address box. I noticed when I open my home page I load from a US server then when Facebook is opened the system slows down and the server changes to Ireland. Keyboard and mouse issues have also developed. Random letters are skipped and random words are accepted as correct spelling with obvious letter omitted. Right mouse click stopped functioning.

OS: Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya, Language en-US

Mozilla Firefox version: Linux Mint 56(64 bit) mint 1.0

Comment: Terminal su authorization is suspended and I can not find a work around

Comment: This is like 5 or 6 different questions put into one. This is not how we work here. This time I answered most of them. But try always put one single answerable question on our site.

Comment: Re. the above duplicate, the Ubuntu packages work fine in Mint.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

> I installed `rkhunter` 1.4.2 but I wanted `rkhunter` 1.4.4.

You can download the 1.4.4 version here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/rkhunter/files/rkhunter/1.4.4/

And install it yourself, read the README.txt for information about recent changes. Be sure to check its gpg signature and sha hash.

Then to install it:

- you should first <strike>uninstall</strike> purge the packaged version of `rkhunter`, i.e. including everything, like previous configuration:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge rkhunter
  ```
- extract the archive `rkhunter-1.4.4.tar.gz`
- run `./installer.sh` to get help
- also, be sure to follow [the official README](http://rkhunter.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rkhunter/rkhunter/files/README)

---

Regarding:

```
Warning: The command '/usr/bin/lwp-request' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/lwp-request: a /usr/bin/perl -w script, ASCII text executable
```

is a *normal* warning, even if you update your `rkhunter` definitions and file statuses with:

```
sudo rkhunter --update
sudo rkhunter --propupd
```

and then check with:

```
sudo rkhunter --check --enable all --disable none --skip-keypress --report-warnings-only
```

I still get this warning and it is harmless.

You can read the perl script for finding out, what it is doing with:

```
cat /usr/bin/lwp-request
```

I did and it does not sound suspicious to me.

---

Regarding:

```
Checking /dev for suspicious file types                  [ Warning ]
Checking for hidden files and directories                [ Warning ]
```

This is also harmless, nothing to be worried about.

---

Regarding:

```
Terminal su authorization is suspended
```

You can make yourself `root` with:

```
sudo -i
```

instead of `su`.